# Batch file stop running after dropping Sql server database

Tags: batch-file

I have created a batch file where I am dropping 2 databases. After dropping these databases batch does not run next commands and showing message `1>` as shown in screenshot:
[[image: screenshot].](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaaH2.png)

**Code:**

```
SqlCmd -S %sqlServer% -q "IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'%applicationDB%') Begin DROP DATABASE %applicationDB% End; IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'%frameworkDB%') Begin DROP DATABASE %frameworkDB% End"

echo Database Dropped..
```

It has not shown a message after dropping databases like `Database Dropped..`.

**Note:**
When user enters `y` it will start dropping databases as shown in above code.

**Edit:**

```
set sqlServer=mypc\ENTERPRISE2014
set applicationDB=Application_4_0_2_0
set frameworkDB=Framework_4_0_2_0
```

These variables does not contain any space or special characters. May be the issue is with instance name which may be replaced with server-name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command for sqlcmd should use -Q(capital Q) to exit from sqlcmd.

```
 SqlCmd -S %sqlServer% -Q "IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'%applicationDB%') Begin DROP DATABASE %applicationDB% End; IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'%frameworkDB%') Begin DROP DATABASE %frameworkDB% End"

    echo Database Dropped..
```

[sqlcmd utilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017)